# Se sembler vs sembler

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I said to a French person

> Tous les mots en français semblent pareils quand parlés

But he corrected me to say

> Tous les mots en français me semblent être pareils quand parlés

Why do I have to say "Se sembler être" instead of just "Sembler"?

Is there a certain rule for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all : *Quand parlé(s)*, although correct, is not the best way of saying this. In France (I don't know about Quebec or other french-speaking countries though), the most idiomatic and frequent way of saying this is *à l'oral*. So you sentence would be :

> Tous les mots en français me semblent être pareils **à l'oral**.

You can even improve the sentence by saying :

> Tous les mots <strike>en</strike> français me semblent <strike>être</strike> pareils **à l'oral**.

But this is all another story. Now back to the topic.

---

Consider the same sentence in english :

> All french words seem alike **to me** when spoken.

If you just used *semblent* without *me*, it would be exactly like if you removed the *to me* from the above sentence.
Which would make this statement a general truth : to **everyone**, french words seem alike.

However, what you mean is that **to you** - and only to you -, the words really sound the same. That's why you have to refer to yourself using *me*.

Now the person you told this to could say :

> J'ai parlé avec Marco, et il m'a dit que tous les mots français **lui** semblent pareils à l'oral.

He or she could also ask you :

> Est-ce bien toi qui m'a dit que tous les mots français **te** semblent pareils à l'oral ?

So as you see, this has nothing to do with the verb *se sembler*, which doesn't even exist.
This is just used to avoid making the sentence a general statement by "linking" it to the person for who it is true.

Here is all the words that can be used here depending on the subject :

- je -> **me**
- tu -> **te**
- il/elle -> **lui**
- nous -> **nous**
- vous-> **vous**
- ils/elles -> **leur**

I hope I helped you ;)

Comment: Thank you! But an additional question :) Why did you add "Bien" there?

Comment: This is an idiomatic way of asking for confirmation when you think the answer is yes but are not totally sure. For example I could ask you : *Ton prénom, c'est bien Marco ?*, because according to your username I am pretty sure it is, however this is not 100% sure : you could be using a fake name.

Comment: Could “se **res**sembler” be used to express the idea of a general truth with:… “Tous les mots français se ressemblent à l'oral » (without having to include *pareils* ?  If so, could you fit a *me* somewhere in it to narrow it to “to me” or would something like “D’apres moi” be required? Thanks and +1

Comment: @PapaPoule Yes, *se ressembler* is a very good option - actually this is what I'd use. I'd say : *Je trouve que tous les mots français se ressemblent à l'oral*, or maybe *Pour moi, tous les mots français se ressemblent à l'oral*.